# Flagged messages via Office 365 REST API?

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm looking for a way to detect & set the 'flagged' status of an email using the Office 365 REST Message API.  I don't see 'Flag' listed as a property of a [REST Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage), though I do see it listed under [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.flag(v=exchg.80).aspx).

I've attempted to make a REST call adding Flag to filtered properties, as well as SingleValueExtendedProperties and MultiValueExtendedProperties like:

```
/folders/inbox/messages?$top=50&$select=Subject,...,Flag
/folders/inbox/messages?$top=50&$select=Subject,...,SingleValueExtendedProperties
/folders/inbox/messages?$top=50&$select=Subject,...,MultiValueExtendedProperties
```

all of these have come back with some form of:

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri","message":"Could not find a property named \\\'Flag\\\' on type \\\'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message\\\'."}}
```

Any suggestions on how to get access to the Outlook 'Flag' property via the REST API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There is now a `Flag` property on `Message` on the `/beta` endpoint. This is the **recommended** way to do this. I'll leave the other information there for historical purposes and to help folks trying to set other extended properties.

Now you can get/set flag status much easier. The [`Message` entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) now has a `Flag` property of type `FollowupFlag`. (If you don't see it at that link, be sure that the `beta` version is selected at the top of the page).

You can mark a message as flagged by sending a `PATCH` with the following payload:

```
{
  "Flag": {
    "FlagStatus": "Flagged"
  }
}
```

---

**OLD METHOD (Using extended properties)**

> **Note:** We recently made a change to simplify the extended properties format. This change is rolling out to servers now, so I've
>   added the new format to this answer. I've left the old format in case
>   anyone is accessing mailboxes that haven't had the update applied yet.
>   If using the old format and you get an error:
>
> ```
> "Could not find a property named 'PropertyRef' on type 
> 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty'."
> ```
>
> You need to move to the new format.

What you need to do is include an `$expand` query parameter to expand the `SingleValueExtendedProperties` collection, with a `$filter` sub-parameter to indicate the property you want to include. In this case, you want [PidTagFlagStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee158830(v=exchg.80).aspx). Try a query like this:

**New Format:**

```
api/beta/me/messages?$select=Subject,SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'Integer 0x1090')
```

**Old Format:**

```
api/beta/me/messages?$select=Subject,SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyRef eq '0x1090' and Type eq Microsoft.OutlookServices.MapiPropertyType'Integer'))
```

Messages that aren't flagged at all will just not have that property returned. Messages that do will look something like this:

**New Format:**

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Users('JasonJ@jasonjohdemo.onmicrosoft.com')/Messages('AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA=')",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCzND\"",
  "Id": "AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA=",
  "Subject": "Test Flag",
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA%3D')/SingleValueExtendedProperties",
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "PropertyId": "Integer 0x1090",
      "Value": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Old Format:**

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Users('JasonJ@jasonjohdemo.onmicrosoft.com')/Messages('AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA=')",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCzND\"",
  "Id": "AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA=",
  "Subject": "Test Flag",
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGQ4Yzc2NDkwLTYxYmItNDZmYS1iZjI1LTYyNmY4NTZkMjI1NgBGAAAAAADwPSus7EwaR6q1wNtgoqEMBwDpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAAAAEgAADpfBfj8UPUTqu4bEwGpnFMAAAjCUJGAAA%3D')/SingleValueExtendedProperties",
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "PropertyRef": "0x1090",
      "Type": "Integer",
      "Value": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Setting the flag is as simple as sending a PATCH to the message with that property in the `SingleValueExtendedProperties` collection:

**New Format:**

```
PATCH https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/messages/{id}

{
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "PropertyId": "Integer 0x1090",
      "Value": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Old Format:**

```
PATCH https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/messages/{id}

{
  "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
      "PropertyRef": "0x1090",
      "Type": "Integer",
      "Value": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, per [MS-OXOFLAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433487(v=exchg.80).aspx), a value of 2 means flagged for follow up, and 1 means flag completed.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  Is there a sister 'set flag' call I can make as well?  E.g. if I use the beta endpoint can I PATCH the flag value?

Comment: This answer was working great for me until today.  Looks like Microsoft might have changed something.  I'm getting an error message now when I try to read or set these values.

Comment: Yep, you're right. There was a change that is rolling out to the extended properties format. I'll update my answer with the new format.

Comment: Thank you for the timely answer.  Is there a way to get pre-notification of breaking changes?  It's difficult to envision creating a product that uses these APIs in the current state of change.

Comment: Completely understand. This change got deployed without advanced notice to the documentation folks, which caused a bit of confusion. Keep in mind too that this is the `beta` endpoint, so things can change a little more rapidly here than in the `1.0` endpoint.